USB flash drive sporadically corrupting TIFF and BMP files
I have a USB flash drive I am using to transfer photos from one Windows 10 machine to another. It can move Excel files and text files fine.
But, occasionally I try to move a .TIFF or .BMP file and it opens with errors saying Windows Photo Viewer doesn't recognize the format, the header is unrecognizable, etc. What is odd is it only does this for some photos and not others. It doesn't seem size dependent because some bigger files successfully transferred.
The files successfully open on the original machine, so I don't think they are written improperly. Additionally, using someone else's USB flash drive, all files move over fine. I opened the 'corrupted' file on my USB flash drive and on the original machine and looked at the first few lines of gibberish and they look the same.
I re-formatted my USB flash drive with exFAT, but the issue persists.
What is even going on? At this point I'm more curious than anything. Please let me know if any additional information would be helpful!

The USB drive might be failing or have bad sectors, leading to partial file corruption. Try using a different USB drive, or run a diagnostic tool like CHKDSK to check for errors.
The issue has nothing to do with the files' format, the small .xls and .txt files are likely to be stored in healthy sectors of your drive.
.TIFF and .BMP files usually take a whole lot more storage space, hence the likelihood of being partly stored in defective media increases with size.

Basics:
I'd strongly suggest you use Eject before removing the flash drive from the source
If your problem does not disappear, then you're likely to have a hardware problem
(=> replace that USB drive).
There IS a reason to use unmount on Linux:en
